# How to Shrink a Video File Size (swift 5)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

i'm shocked that such a common problem have so little posts/tutorials about it!
(google it your self and see)

input: video url (probably from photo lib.)
output: video url (compressed, low quality)

all the solutions i found were either too old/in Obj C/wrong even!

thank you for taking the time to help me :)

Comment: If you're so shocked, you're welcome to contribute a solution to the open source world! Nobody owes anyone to write an open source library.

Answer (score -1):

i found a very helpful post here:

https://medium.com/samkirkiles/swift-using-avassetwriter-to-compress-video-files-for-network-transfer-4dcc7b4288c5

the version used is swift 3, but xcode with fix all the problems.

but it only compress .mov files, which is okay since this is the format used by apple (iPhones, macs, etc..)

hope it helps.

(to adjust the compression degree, multiply the bitrate by some constant)